# How to host a R leaflet map on line

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using an R package called leaftlet to produce a map. Here is my R script which is a proof of concept.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("rstudio/leaflet")
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, 
               popup="<img src='https://www.dropbox.com/s/no328r9hd7qsp9u/bfc243a3jw1eteydahszmj20hs0hsdof.jpg?dl=1' width = '45' height = '45'>")
m

saveWidget(m, file = "conceptproof.html", selfcontained = F)
```

I know how to produce a interactive map in leaflet and also how to save it locally (in my own desktop). However the question is how can I host that html file online? What I want is I would like to send a link to some of my friends and when they click on that link they can go to a webpage and see the map I created (Ideally I don't want the map to be downloaded when people clicking the link).

I have tried google drive and dropbox without any luck. I asked some people and also searched online. It seems that I need a server or something like that which is something I'm not familiar with. Do I really need a server or is there a simpler way of doing this (say github)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to upload the html file to a server and link to that. Here's an example: http://biolitika.si/dab/gene_data.html You can host your own server. If you're on Windows, try [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)).

Comment: Another option is to use `shiny` and create a webapp.

Comment: @Teja K If I use shiny, do I need to setup a server?

Comment: @Lambo no, `shiny` does that for you. Literally all you have to do is build the map and click publish. You can find more info [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/).

Comment: you could also try out http://rpubs.com/

Answer (score 0):

The storage bucket offered by the Google Cloud Platform works really well. You just have to share all your files publicly, and then you can embed your html public link onto a website.